# change colour of partial text css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way of achieving a different colour on part of text, via css or script, based on a shape outline e.g a circle or oval curve...with CSS or JS only.

An example is this, see how the colour of the S and part of the U are different based on the image?-
example of effect
[image]

Theres a similar question but this is in illustrator - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20127/text-silhouette-change-color-in-middle-of-a-letter-illustrator

Instinct says no way, but there could be some magical clipping effect that can achieve the same?

Comment: It's possible, but not easy. You'd could use SVG with a path for both elements (the silhouette and the text) and then somehow clip them both to get an intersection path which can then be coloured.

Comment: You need SVG and CSS to do this... Eh, kinda too broad or tough for Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this is a bad question, even if it does not exactly follow the rules of SO

Answer (score 3):

I was a bit slower than Emil Østervig, but I wanted to write the same :-) I created a little example for the mix blend mode property, which does NOT work in IE and Edge. I dont think you can exactly recreate your Image with pure CSS, but it is an interesting option to maybe dig a bit deeper.

```css
.image {
  background: url(http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/wolf-xxl.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.inverted {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 256px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="inverted">
    Wolf <br>
    Wolf <br>
    Wolf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two or more ways to do that. I can come up with 2 on the spot.

One solution would be to use SVG text. Which i cant advise if you have a lot of places or dynamic text. Animating SVG text is a bit complicated sometimes.

What you could do instead is using mix-blend-mode css. It allows blending colors of text and backgrounds. Kind of how you might know it from Photoshop or Illustrator.

You can read more about it here on [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/). You might wan't to check up on browser compatibility, since mix-blend-mode is poorly supported in general. You can check out which browser can make use of it here on [Caniuse](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode).

If you need inspiration for workarounds or examples of usage you could always search codepen.io for mix-blend-mode or something similar.